# making output buffer work

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have the following crazy snippet as a test ground for ob_start functionality.

```
ob_start();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100000000; $i++) {       
    echo '<li>',$i, ' ',date("H:i:s");
    ob_flush();
}
```

I wait minutes before I can see something on the screen.
For minutes, I look at a blank page with a status message "waiting for www.myserver.com" with a "loading..." message on the browser title.

Isn't ob_flush to prevent exactly this behaviour?

What do you do to the above snippet so that when you run it, you get an instant flow of text on your browser?

Comment: You dont close <li> and expect partial render ? And why you just dont try this with print or echo ?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with client side. Whether you use print or close the li makes 0 difference. The question has to do with ob_start behaviour.

Comment: Browsers hate to render not closed tags. Thats why table-design is slow. Also he can have output buffering on webserver.

Comment: When I write the same code in ASP, browser shows the output instantly. ASP equivalent of the above code uses response.buffer=TRUE ( for ob_Start()) and response.flush ( for ob_flush() counterparts. I can leave the echo <li> as is. Browser would show the output immediately. I do understand and totally agree with the closing tags point and the table matter you are referring to, but here that does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

adding the line

```
flush();
```

right after the

```
    ob_flush();
```

does the trick. browser shows the input instantly and you get a streaming text until the whole thing dumped on the browser or script times out.

DON'T TRY THIS SNIPPET CAUSE IT WOULD WASTE A LOT OF BANDWIDTH.

Does any one know why adding the flush() after the ob_flush make it happen?

NOTE THAT, just the flush() without the ob_flush() or just the ob_flush() without the flush() does not work.